# SQL parameters - scalar variable

Tags: sql, parameters

I am trying to set a SQL parameter to a decimal, but when I run my code I get an error

> must declare the scalar variable @Per_Cent..

The code is below, thanks in advance

```
SqlParameter PerCent = new SqlParameter("@PerCent", SqlDbType.Decimal, 5); 
PerCent.Value = PerCentV;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error refers to variable named "@Per_Cent" but you're adding a parameter called "@PerCent"....

Also, I'm assuming you are then adding that SqlParameter to the SqlCommand

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you have your param in your query defined as `@Per_Cent`

And you are declaring it's value with `@PerCent`

So make these equal, add it to your `SqlCommand.Parameters` and it should work!

Comment: Please post your full query so we can see